# How do a bulk addition in sql relation (based off of query results in another relation)?

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I do this question in sql (taken from glassdoor):

You have a table where you have date, user_id, song_id and count. It shows at the end of each day how many times in her history a user has listened to a given song. So count is cumulative sum.
You have to update this on a daily basis based on a second table that records in real time when a user listens to a given song. Basically, at the end of each day, you go to this second table and pull a count of each user/song combination and then add this count to the first table that has the lifetime count.

I particularly do not know how to update a table in such a bulk/massive/looping type of way and would appreciate the mysql code to achieve something like that. I haven't written the code because I do not know how to do such a large scale addition in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't add anything to the existing counts, you insert a new record for that day with the total play count as on that day. Old records in the history table are not updated

At the end of each day, you run this:

```
INSERT INTO playhistory
SELECT CURDATE(), user_id, song_id, count(*)
FROM individualplays
GROUP BY user_id, song_id
```

Individualplays table holds the user and song ids for all time. If a new user plays the same song 10 times today, the count(*) will be 10. Tomorrow if she plays that song another 5 times, the count will now be 15

If you cannot guarantee to run the query right at the end of the day, your individualplays table needs the date and time that a song was played, then at any time the day after, you can update your history table thus:

```
INSERT INTO playhistory
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), user_id, song_id, count(*)
FROM individualplays
WHERE playdate < CURDATE()
GROUP BY user_id, song_id
```

its a shame you're using MySQL actually, because more powerful rdbms can do the history entirely out of the individualplays table dynamically through use of analytic/window functions; devices that can do things like counting all the rows from the start of time, to the current row, per user/song. You can simulate these in MySQL but it's pretty nasty - it basically would involve joining the individualplays table to itself on userid=userid,songid=songid and playdate